# Resolving ambiguity in declaration of size_t

Tags: c++, include, resharper, ambiguity

I recently started using ReSharper and am now trying to solve all the warnings. One warning I get is with the declaration of a const size_t in my stdafx.h header file, it is an ambiguous symbol. See below my header declaration file with the problem:

```
#pragma once

const size_t X = 0;     //No Ambiguity, size_t declared in vcruntime.h
#include <string>
const size_t Y = 0;     //Ambiguity, size_t declared in vcruntime.h and xlocinfo.h
```

Despite this ambiguity the code compiles and runs fine in my VS-Studio on Windows 10. Later I need to port the code to Linux.

**How can I resolve this ambiguity.**

Note that I of course need to use the string header. Also I could just simply declare these constants before any inclusions, but that does not seem a nice solution to me. By the way I have this same ambiguity throughout my project.

Comment: The code you've shown is not valid because there is no definition of `size_t` at the point where it is first used. Post real code.

Comment: It is a visual studio generated project and as stated compiles and runs without problems. Of course VS adds some dependencies, but they are shown in the code fragment in the comment.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your compiler. Again: there **is no definition** of `size_t` at the point where it is first used. Just look at the code you've posted.

Comment: Sigh. You deleted the comment that I replied to. "Of course VS adds some dependencies..." is where the problem lies, not in the code you've shown.

Comment: To disable all the non-standard compliant extensions that VS enables by default, compile with the ["/Za" flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx).

Comment: The offending snippet of code seems to be in xlocinfo.h, and it's not even a declaration of `size_`, only a usage (as far as I dug into it). locinfo.h L143: `_ACRTIMP size_t __cdecl _Strftime(_Out_writes_z_(_Maxsize) char *,
 _In_ size_t _Maxsize, _In_z_ const char *, _In_ const struct tm *,
 _In_opt_ void *);`

Disabling ReSharper analysis fixes this.
Disabling language extensions does *not* immediately fix this (`/Za`).

Include graph: https://i.imgur.com/l55K4fs.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. Please create an issue with the steps to reproduce in the [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=project:%20%7BReSharper%20C%2B%2B%7D) and the team will take a look.